# Duplicate entry 'Exotical' for key 'naam'

Tags: mysql

So I ran into this error:

```
Duplicate entry 'Exotical' for key 'naam'
```

when I try to insert a new registered user in my database. The weird thing is, it does insert users in the DB, but still it throws that error...
Here's my table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ht_users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `last_seen` varchar(55) NOT NULL,
  `naam` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `pass` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `pin` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `email_activation` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `last_ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `reg_ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `reg_date` varchar(10) NOT NULL,
  `last_login` varchar(8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '00000000',
  `rank` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
  `rank2` varchar(4) DEFAULT NULL,
  `kladblok` text,
  `listenerminutes` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `shouts_liked` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `mail_solli` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `mail_event` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '1',
  `online` varchar(12) NOT NULL DEFAULT '000000000000',
  `skype` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `permban` enum('0','1') NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `goldrecords` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `signature` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY `naam` (`naam`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1;
```

I don't know if any code is needed, so please Say so if you do.

Thanks

Comment: are you sure it still inserts all the rows...?  you're trying to put in duplicate values for that field.  are you sure it just doesn't put one of them in there?

Comment: You are naming your unique key with the same name of the field thats why exotical name. Change it to `UNIQUE KEY `uk_naam` (`naam`)`. I will post as an answer if it works. I'm pretty sure it is this.

Comment: Can you share the table description? **DESC ht_users;**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See you have put the same name of the field for the `UNIQUE KEY`.

So changing the name would of the unique key would solve the problem..

You can use something like  `UNIQUE KEY anyname ('naam')`

See [working demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6b9bd0)